# How can I fire custom events on canvas in fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I want to register JavaScript events on canvas in fabric.js. How can I fire custom events on canvas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to extend fabricjs event system with your custom events, that is pretty simple:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
// listen for any event like fabricjs do
canvas.on('custom:event', function(event) {
  // you will have your data here in `event` object 
});
// fire any event with any payload you want
canvas.fire('custom:event', { any: 'payload' });
```

I prefer this way as you do not use any other libs and still have the same syntax in all the cases (native and custom events).

**UPDATE!**
Do not forget that you should define listener BEFORE firing an event!
Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gpstmp/5ffc7xt8/1/) fiddle with a working example.

Comment: thanks peter for feedback. I will try this solution.

Comment: I have tried this solution but its not working for me.

Comment: @PiyushDholariya you'd better add a fiddle or something else if you have a problem. I think you just fire the event BEFORE adding a listener. You can check my update in the post with a link to a working fiddle.