# Call fabricjs event continuously

Tags: fabricjs

I'm calling custom event in this way:
[How can I fire custom events on canvas in Fabric JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235186/how-can-i-fire-custom-events-on-canvas-in-fabric-js)

Is there a way to call it continuously like the object:scaling/moving events?

**SOLUTION:**

I solved this problem using the object:moving event:

```
canvas.on({'object:moving': handleMovement});
...
var handleMovement = function (event) {

    //only when a specific corner was dragged
    if (event.target.__corner == 'mb') {
        //reset original position
        event.target.top = event.target.originalState.top;
        event.target.left = event.target.originalState.left;
        //do other stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call the event continuously, you could wrap it in a while loop, or use some sort of timeout.

```
while (shouldFire) {
    canvas.trigger(event);
}
```

or

```
setTimeout(triggerEvent, 100);
function triggerEvent() {
    canvas.trigger(event);
    setTimeout(triggerEvent, 100);
}
```

However, that might not be ideal for the user (especially the while).

While the object:scaling/moving events may appear to be called continuously, I believe they are simply being called incredibly rapidly in response to user interaction.  There's a good [event demo](http://fabricjs.com/events) on the fabricjs website for looking at this.  If you select an object and simply hold it stationary, there are no events fired by the canvas.  Instead, the events are only fired in response to user movement, such as dragging the shape around the canvas.  So, instead of trying to make the events continuously fired, you could simply listen for small changes in the user's input.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I solved my problem changing entirely the approach to the situation. I used the object:moving event checking if specific corner was dragged and then resetting it to previous position.